# Efficient logging solution for multiple threads in C

Tags: c, linux, logging

I have a C program which has multiple worker threads.   There is a main thread which periodically (every 0.2s) does some basic checks (i.e. has a thread finished, has a signal been received, etc).   At each check, I would like to write to a log file any data that any of the threads may have in their log buffer to a single log file.

My initial idea was to simply open the log file, write the data from all the threads and then close it again.   I am worried that this might be too much of an overhead seeing as these checks occur every 0.2s.

So my question is - is this scenario inefficient?

If so, can anyone suggest a better solution?

I thought of leaving the file descriptor open and just writing new data on every check, but then there is the problem if somehow the physical file gets deleted, the program would never know (without rechecking, and in this case we might as well just open the file again) and logging data would be lost.

(This program is designed to run for very long periods of time, so the fact that log file will be deleted at some point is basically guaranteed due to log rotation.)

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `syslog()` and letting the syslog daemon take care of writing the files for you?

Comment: The daemon itself does use syslog, but I really wanted a separate log, well, two in fact, to collect STDOUT and STDERR of the sub-processes created in each thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought of leaving the file descriptor open and just writing new data on every check, but then there is the problem if somehow the physical file gets deleted, the program would never know (without rechecking, and in this case we might as well just open the file again) and logging data would be lost.

The standard solution on UNIX is to add a signal handler for SIGHUP which closes and re-opens the log file. [Many](http://linux.die.net/man/8/crond) UNIX daemons do this for precisely this purpose, to support log rotation. Call `kill -HUP <pid>` in your log rotation script and you're good to go.

([Some programs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xinetd) will also treat SIGHUP as a cue to re-read their configuration files, so you can make configuration changes on the fly without having to restart processes.)

Comment: Aha, so I should stick with opening the file once and keep it open until either the process shuts down of a SIHUP is received... great to hear this is the standard solution - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there isn't much of a good solution. I would suggest to write a timer that runs separately from your main 0.2s check, and checks the logfile buffers and write them to disk.

I am working on something network based that could solve this (I have had the same problem) with excellent performance, fire me a message on [github](https://github.com/Poincare) for details.

Comment: The problem is that I'd really like to write to the log file as soon as there is log data waiting from the threads.   The threads themselves fork and the child process is replaced by a new process of another program - the log data is from these processes and so it ideally needs to be written to the log as soon as the process writes it for monitoring purposes.